# How to do atomic operations like $push $pull $set etc. in Ecto MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, elixir, ecto

I'm using mongodb_ecto and I want to know how can I do operations like $push or $pull on a deeply nested field? At the moment I write back the whole document which sometimes causes false data to be in the DB due to a race-condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I kind of figured it out. Do not use Ecto for this. In some cases you need the [MongoDB positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/positional/) and this can only be done directly via the Mongo-Adapter. Now for some usage examples:

I have a doucment with a list of options. Options have an ID, a label and list of userIDs who voted for this option.

BTW to generate an ObjectID (which is needed for talking directly to the MongoDB-Adapter) use this:

```
id = "584a5b9419d51d724d146e3f" # string form
value = (for <<hex::16 <- id>>, into: <<>>, do: <<String.to_integer(<<hex::16>>, 16)::8>>)
object_id = %BSON.ObjectId{value: value}
```

And now for some examples:

```
# update label of option
Mongo.update_one(Repo.Pool, "polls",
  %{"_id" => document_id, "options.id" => option_id}, # query
  %{"$set" => %{"data.options.$.label" => new_label}} # update
)

# add new option to poll
Mongo.update_one(Repo.Pool, "polls",
  %{"_id" => document_id},
  %{"$addToSet" => %{"options" => %{label: label, id: random_new_id, votes: []}}}
)

# add user_id to option
Mongo.update_one(Repo.Pool, "polls",
  %{"_id" => document_id, "options.id" => option_id},
  %{"$addToSet" => %{"options.$.votes" => user_id}}
)

# remove user_id form option
Mongo.update_one(Repo.Pool, "polls",
  %{"_id" => document_id, "options.id" => option_id},
  %{"$pull" => %{"data.options.$.votes" => user_id}}
)
```